# Validate Logstash input using JSON schema

Tags: json, validation, schema, logstash

I push the JSON data into logstash using HTTP plugin. I am parsing it using JSON plugin and it all works fine. I have also created a JSON schema for this data.

The problem is: is there a possibility to validate the data using JSON schema directly in Logstash? I would want to make sure that all types match my schema and in some cases, that values in some field match one of the "enum" array in JSON schema.

Comment: I have the same question. Any updates here?

Comment: Are there any updates on this topic?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not supported by logstash you will need to install a custom plugin.

Looking for a solution I found this plugin that solved my issue https://github.com/ebuildy/logstash-filter-schema_validation .

It is validation on the whole event and not a specific field as you can see in the rb code here => https://github.com/ebuildy/logstash-filter-schema_validation/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/schema_validation.rb#L47.

After installing the plugin using following command:

```
logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-schema_validation
```

You can add this to the logstash filter:

```
 schema_validation
            {
                schema => "/path/to/schemas/logschemav2.json"
                report_field => "_json_validation_errors"
                strict => false
            }
```

You can then use the _json_validation_errors field in the logstash logic.

The report field will contain messages like:

```
The property '#/log' did not contain a required property of 'timestamp' in schema file:///path/to/schemas/logschemav2.json#,
```

Comment: I added my solution